# Proving that for every integer n that is not a multiple of 2 or 5 there is another integer that is made up of 1s that can be divided by n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for every integer $n$, divisible by neither $2$ nor $5$, there exists an integer $m$, whose decimal representation consists only of $1$s, which is divisible by $n$ (e.g. for $n=13$, we have $m=111111$ divisible by $13$).

Sorry if the format is not up to standard.

Comment: I presume that by "not made up of 1s" you mean "not 1 or 11 or 111 or 1111, etc."  Is that correct?

Comment: Hint:  Do you remember how when you were in elementary school you were taught how to turn an infinitely repeating decimal into a fraction?  Did you every notice those fractions only had $9$s in the denominator?

Comment: Consider this.  $\frac 17 = 0.14285714285714285714285714285714...$ so $1000000*\frac 17 = 142857.14285714285714285714285714285714...$ so $999999*\frac 17 = 142857$.  And so $17*142857 = 999999= 111111*9$.  And so $7*\frac {142857}9 =7*15873=111111$.  Can you generalize that?